# Jenkins Fails to Send Test Reports to Gmail Due to Security Concerns

Tags: jenkins, oauth-2.0, smtp, gmail, google-oauth

When I execute tests in Jenkins, it doesn't send an email, even though at the end of the test, it indicates "send mail".

Upon checking my Google account, I encountered a security alert. Google's security section flagged the tokens I generated for Jenkins as suspicious activities. How can I resolve this issue?

Follow-up:
Can you provide guidance on addressing this situation with Gmail and Jenkins?